# How to set serial number in Antd Table for each row when we use pagination

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Antd Table in my react js project. I have a table with pagination set to 10 entries per page. my problem is when I click on the second page I see the serial number starts again from 1 instead of 11. its not in order. here is my code.

**component**

```
function createColumns(view, edit, remove, activate) {
 return [
{
  title: 'S NO',
  key: 'sno',
  width: '20px',
  render: (text, object, index) =>return  index + 1

},
...
...

}
 <TableWrapper
          rowKey={obj => obj.id}
          pagination={{ pageSize: 10 }}
          columns={this.columns}
          locale={{ emptyText: 'No data found' }}
          dataSource={data}              
        />
```

I have tried the solutions provided in the comment of this [github issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/8311) but it didn't work. what am I missing here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `index` field referred here is relative to the data currently rendered, so it will always start from 0 on a new page. To improvise and fit your situation, you can store the current page number and use it to change the `index`

```
const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
return (
  <Table
    dataSource={data}
    pagination={{
      onChange(current) {
        setPage(current);
      }
    }}
  >
    <Column
      title="Index"
      key="index"
      render={(value, item, index) => (page - 1) * 10 + index}
    />
    ...
  </Table>
)
```

Answer (score 4):

if you have pagination and the pagination is dynamic based on the dropdown selection for the table you can use this.

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

const [paginationSize, setPaginationSize] = useState(25); //your current default pagination size 25
const columns: any = [
{
  title: '#',
  key: 'index',
  width: "20px",
  render: (text: string, record: any, index: number) => (page - 1) * paginationSize + index + 1,
}]
return(
<Table
    pagination={{
      onChange(current, pageSize) {
        setPage(current);
        setPaginationSize(pageSize)
      },
      defaultPageSize: 25, hideOnSinglePage: true, showSizeChanger: true
    }}columns={columns}
    dataSource={tableData} />
)
```

Answer (score 3):

To start index from 1

```
render={(value, item, index) => (page - 1) * 10 + index + 1}
```