# How to set serial number in Antd Table and serial no. should start from (pageno -1) *10+1?

Tags: reactjs, antd

**How to set serial number in Antd Table and serial no. should be start from (pageno -1) *10+1 ?**
I can set in when pagination button is clicked but i don't know how it would be

```
 <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data_new}
        className="customtable textCenter"
        showSorterTooltip={false}
        pagination={{
          onChange(current) {
            setPage(current);
          }
        }}
      />
```

```
    // {
    //   title: 'S.No.',
    //   dataIndex: 'num',
      
    // },
    {
      title: 'Date/Time',
      dataIndex: 'date',
    },
    {
      title: 'Email',
      dataIndex: 'email',
    },
    {
      title: 'URL',
      dataIndex: 'url',
    },
    {
      title: 'Count',
      dataIndex: 'count',
    },
  ];
 const data_new = [];
 let num=0
 if(refers) {
  refers.forEach((refer) => {
    num=num+1
     data_new.push({
       key: 1,
       num: num,
       date:refer.date,
       email:refer.refer_by_name,
       count:refer.sign_up_count,
       url:refer.url
     });
   })
 }
```

**The all page index starting from 1 please help**

Comment: This answer may help you to set the serial number.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657935/how-to-set-serial-number-in-antd-table-for-each-row-when-we-use-pagination?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `render` for sorting

```js
const columns = [
        {
            title: 'SL ID',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            key: 'id',
            sorter: (a, b) => a.id - b.id,
            render: (id, record, index) => { ++index; return index; },
            showSorterTooltip: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Company Type',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            key: 'name',
        },
        {
            title: 'Description',
            dataIndex: 'description',
            key: 'description',
        }
    ];
```